# How to set metadata for controller and action methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I'm using this code for displaying all controllers name with action methods:

```
public ActionResult GetAllControllers()
        {
            var controllers = typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(typeof (IController).IsAssignableFrom);
            return View(controllers.ToList());
        }
```

View:

```
<ul id="treeView">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <li>
                @item.Name
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var action in item.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Where(method => typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType)))
                    {
                        <li>@action.Name</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
    }

</ul>
```

The result is look like this:

```
HomeController
     Index
     About
MainController
     Index
     Create
     Edit
     Delete
...
```

Now my question is that: Is there any way to set a name for controller and action method as display result? For example something like this:

```
[SetName("MainPage")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [SetName("ProductList")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //
    }
    // other action methods
}
```

So in this case the result for displaying controllers name and action methods would be:

```
MainPage
   ProductList
...
```

Comment: I am so fluent C# user, but probalby you can do it with filters.

Comment: You can create your own attributes and tag your methods with them. The data they contain are available through reflection which you are already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new attribute class, then read the attributes by `GetCustomAttributes()` method on `Property` and `Class`